# Getting the next ID value from a table sometimes returns duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `UniqueIDStore` that gives me last `UniqueID` given from the database. When application needs unique id, application would execute following stored procedure and it does following things,

1. Get last `UniqueID` from `UniqueIDStore` table
2. Increment by one
3. Save the latest `UniqueID` to `UniqueIDStore` table.

When application executes this stored procedure from different database connections/java processes, it returns me duplicate id’s sometime, I don’t know why.

`UniqueIDStore` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UniqueIDStore](
    [UniqueId] [bigint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Stored procedure is:

```
CREATE    PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_UniqueID] @blockSize int = 1 
AS  
    DECLARE @uniqueId BIGINT;
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR local FOR SELECT UNIQUEID FROM UniqueIDStore FOR UPDATE OF UNIQUEID;
    OPEN C1;
    SELECT UNIQUEID FROM UniqueIDStore;
    FETCH C1 INTO @uniqueId;
    UPDATE UniqueIDStore SET UNIQUEID = @uniqueId + @blockSize;
    CLOSE C1;
GO
```

I am not an SQL Server expert; can someone help me on this fixing stored procedure to synchronize the requests?

Comment: Lookup identity columns. In 2012, you could also look at sequences. If your stuck on this idea try "select (select max(UNIQUEID) from UniqueIDStorage) + 1" in your sp.

Comment: Why would you use this rather than the built in option, `IDENTITY`? I don't see this ever working I'm afraid, it's subject to many factors such as concurrent requests, transactions being rolled back, potentially dirty reads etc.

Comment: Are you coming from an Oracle background (with next-sequence (next val))?

Comment: Your solution is **NOT SAFE** under load. Plain and simple. You cannot use this simplistic code to achieve what you're looking for. See the duplicate I link to - study Remus Rusanu's answer - his solution is the **ONLY** safe solution if you insist on having "manual" sequences (instead of using the much safer `SEQUENCE` db object in SQL Server **2012** or an `INT IDENTITY` column in earlier versions)

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure is not using transactions, so you have no guarantee that someone else won't read the same number after you, but before you could store the new value.

In SQLServer you can use identity for handling primary key generation, like this:

```
create table something (
   id identity int,
   something varchar(50)
);
```

Then, you can do this:

```
 insert into something values ('something');
 insert into something values ('something else');
```

and probably get something like this:

```
| id | something      |
|  1 | something      |
|  2 | something else |
```

Comment: It's not so much the fact the OP isn't using **transactions** - it's the fact he's (a) using a cursor (which is totally unnecessary), and (b) he's doing two separate steps (`SELECT` before `UPDATE`) which can lead to unsafe execution under concurrent load